# Why did my touchpad stop working?

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

All of a sudden my mouse started clicking randomly, sometimes it gets stuck in one position and sometimes starts jumping around. It didn't have any problems before to maybe indicate deteriorating hardware but it didn't happen after an update or anything either. My system is a 20.04.1 Ubuntu in a Hp 250 G6 laptop. Looking online there seems to have been a bug in Ubuntu relating to my issue, but since those posts are old I don't know how relevant those are anymore, and I have tried their solutions to no improvements.
`xinput --list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam: HP Webcam                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Running `synclient` get me this:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Comment: The output is OK. It really may be a hardware problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 May very well be but isn't synclient supposed to give something?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `libinput` is used in modern Ubuntu versions. `syncient` is obsolete.

Comment: Try to boot from a LiveUSB and check how it works there.

Comment: Well I booted today and the problem had fixed itself. The only related change I did yesterday was installing libinput-tools.